# Lag when dragging windows between monitors in KDE

Tags: kde, plasma, kde5

When dragging a window from one monitor to the next (either with alt or by the title bar) there is a slight lag as the mouse passes the boundary. Although not a huge issue it's one of the first things I noticed after the reinstall and for me is quite significant. I'd always prioritise speed over looks in a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is due to the visualization of windows tiling to half of the screen at screen edges.

Disable in **Settings > Desktop behaviour > Screen edges**, uncheck *Tile windows by dragging them to the side of the screen*.

Get the same functionality back again in **Settings > Shortcuts > global keyboard shortcuts** for *kwin* set a global shortcut such as 'Meta+Left/Right' for *Quick Tile Windows to the Left/Right*.